# Is it true that almost all sequences on [0,1] are equidistributed? and almost none are uniformly equidistributed?

Tags: probability, equidistribution

**Definition 1**. A sequence $(x_n)$ of real numbers on $[0,1]$ is said to be *equidistributed* on $[0,1]$ if for any interval $[a,b] \subseteq [0,1]$, the sequence $\frac{\{x_1,\ldots,x_n\} \cap [a,b]}{n}$ converges to $b-a$ as $n \to \infty$.

**Definition 2**. A sequence $(x_n)$ of real numbers on $[0,1]$ is said to be *uniformly equidistributed* (or *well-distributed*) on $[0,1]$ if for any interval $[a,b] \subseteq [0,1]$, the sequence $\frac{\{x_{k+1},\ldots,x_{k+n}\} \cap [a,b]}{n}$ converges to $b-a$ uniformly in $k$ as $n \to \infty$.

For some discussion of these notions, see for example the wikipedia page:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equidistributed_sequence

**Question 1**. What is the probability that a random sequence on $[0,1]$ is equidistributed? Particularly, is it true that almost all sequences on $[0,1]$ are equidistributed?

**Question 2**. What is the probability that a random sequence on $[0,1]$ is uniformly equidistributed? Particularly, is it true that almost none sequences on $[0,1]$ are uniformly equidistributed?

Are these some well-known results?

Comment: What is your measure on the set of sequences?

Comment: Reminds me of the result that almost all real numbers in (0, 1) are normal in all bases yet no one knows of an example of such a number.

Comment: Jonas, actually it turns out that it's a good question. I don't know. I am reading the wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite-dimensional_Lebesgue_measure . So, does it mean that the phrase "almost all sequences" cannot even be well-defined? So, is it true that there is no good or reasonable sense in which Question 1 and Question 2 can be meaningful?

Comment: @HiddenMathematician That was my point, I thought that you could have some specific measure in mind. There is no Lebesgue measure in infinite dimensions, although some attempts have been made to define "appropriate" measures (something like Lebesgue is impossible, meaning that something of what we would like will fail).

Comment: It seems we only need a probability measure on the infinite product space. How about this? (http://mathoverflow.net/questions/85286/proof-of-lomnicki-and-ulam-on-infinite-product-probability-spaces)